# SharePoint 2010 User Profile Picture Synchronization - Missing Updates from ADS

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service, user-profile-property, mysite

right now i've got a problem where i can't get my head wrapped arround it:

The User Profile Pictures within the Thumbnail Attribute of ADS were imported successfully. ([Following this Guide](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/harmeetw/2011/09/10/importing-thumbnail-photos-from-adactive-directory-into-sharepoint-2010/))

Yesterday i noticed, that if we update a Users Photo within ADS, the changed picture won't show in SharePoint MySite.(The Sync is working, it also shows that the Profile was changed on the Day when the ADS picture was updated - checked it within SSM). 
However if i check the DS_Deltaimport Update for the given user it states no changes to the thumbnailPhoto Value, despite the fact that the new Photo shows up within Exchange and other ADS-synced systems, so the Value should have changed...

Maybe someone of you has already encountered this.

What did i do so far:
- Running a Full Sync
- Update-SPProfilePhotoStore

Right now im considering to Delete the mapping, run full sync, recreate the mapping and run a full sync again, but i'd like to avoid that.

Any ideas?

Update 18.04.2017:

After recreating the ADS-Synchronization Mapping the problem still occurs. The old user photos still appear. 
"Funny Thing": The new Thumbnail Photo Octet String is available within the SyncDB, but is not transmitted or recreated within ProfileDB.
UpdatePhotostore etc. doesn't change anything.

My next approach will be to upload the Pictures directly into MySite Photo Gallery and updating the UserProfiles-Picture URL via Powershell.